# Forward fill pandas dataframe without duplicating values in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, all the blank regions are np.nan.

```
         coupler_id   25       26         28        29
timestamp               
2015-12-05 03:02:29                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:04:47                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:09:14                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:12:12                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:23:06                                 12008.0
2015-12-05 03:24:45                                 12017.0
2015-12-05 06:31:20                     12017.0 
2015-12-05 09:36:29                     12011.0 
2015-12-05 23:59:35                                 12017.0
2015-12-06 23:59:38                                 12017.0
```

I want to forward fill the missing values (limit 1) **without duplicating values in rows**. So the above dataframe should look like this:

```
         coupler_id   25       26         28        29
timestamp               
2015-12-05 03:02:29                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:04:47                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:09:14                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:12:12                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:23:06                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:24:45                                 12017.0
2015-12-05 06:31:20                     12017.0 
2015-12-05 09:36:29                     12011.0 
2015-12-05 23:59:35                     12011.0     12017.0
2015-12-06 23:59:38                                 12017.0
```

Edit:

What if there is data in column 25 and 26 and there was not a preceding nan on column 28 index 2015-12-05 03:24:45.

```
         coupler_id   25       26         28        29
timestamp               
2015-12-05 03:02:29                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:04:47                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:09:14                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:12:12                     12017.0     12008.0
2015-12-05 03:23:06   12007.0 12018.0               12008.0
2015-12-05 03:24:45   12033.0 12050.0   12025.0     12017.0
2015-12-05 06:31:20           12033.0   12017.0 
2015-12-05 09:36:29   12008.0           12011.0 
2015-12-05 23:59:35                                 12017.0
2015-12-06 23:59:38                                 12017.0
```

Comment: Just use the limit argument for the fillna function. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna

Comment: That accomplishes the limit 1 requirement, but would generate a duplicate 12017.0 in columns 28 and 29 on index 2015-12-05 06:31:20.

Comment: so no rows can be filled if the filling would generate col28 = col29?

Comment: @Yuca yes, but furthermore, no forward filling should generate a situation that col28 = any(col25, col26, col29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Here's a more general case that checks against all columns:

```
def remove_duplicates(data, ix, names):
    # if only 1 entry, no comparison needed
    if data.notnull().sum() == 1: 
        return data
    # mark all duplicates
    dupes = data.dropna().duplicated(keep=False) 
    if dupes.any():
        for name in names:
            # if previous value was NaN AND current is duplicate, replace with NaN
            if np.isnan(df.loc[ix, name]) & dupes[name]:
                data[name] = np.nan
    return data

filled = df.ffill(limit=1)
filled.apply(lambda row: remove_duplicates(row, row.name, row.index), axis=1)

                          25       26       28       29
2015-12-05 03:02:29      NaN      NaN  12017.0  12008.0
2015-12-05 03:04:47      NaN      NaN  12017.0  12008.0
2015-12-05 03:09:14      NaN      NaN  12017.0  12008.0
2015-12-05 03:12:12      NaN      NaN  12017.0  12008.0
2015-12-05 03:23:06  12007.0  12018.0  12017.0  12008.0
2015-12-05 03:24:45  12033.0  12050.0  12025.0  12017.0
2015-12-05 06:31:20      NaN  12033.0  12017.0      NaN
2015-12-05 09:36:29  12008.0  12033.0  12011.0      NaN
2015-12-05 23:59:35  12008.0      NaN  12011.0  12017.0
2015-12-06 23:59:38      NaN      NaN      NaN  12017.0
```

**Previous answer**
You can use `ffill(limit=1)`, and then check to see if there's a duplicate *and* if one of the preceding columns is `NaN`.

```
import numpy as np

def remove_duplicates(data, ix, names):
    if data[0] - data[1] != 0:
        return data
    if np.isnan(filled.loc[ix-1, names[0]]):
        return [data[0], np.nan]
    elif np.isnan(filled.loc[ix-1, names[1]]):
        return [np.nan, data[1]]
    return data

filled = df[["28","29"]].ffill(limit=1)

df[["28","29"]] = filled.apply(
    lambda row: remove_duplicates(row, row.name, row.index), axis=1
)

df
            coupler_id  25  26       28       29
0  2015-12-05 03:02:29 NaN NaN  12017.0  12008.0
1  2015-12-05 03:04:47 NaN NaN  12017.0  12008.0
2  2015-12-05 03:09:14 NaN NaN  12017.0  12008.0
3  2015-12-05 03:12:12 NaN NaN  12017.0  12008.0
4  2015-12-05 03:23:06 NaN NaN  12017.0  12008.0
5  2015-12-05 03:24:45 NaN NaN      NaN  12017.0
6  2015-12-05 06:31:20 NaN NaN  12017.0      NaN
7  2015-12-05 09:36:29 NaN NaN  12011.0      NaN
8  2015-12-05 23:59:35 NaN NaN  12011.0  12017.0
9  2015-12-06 23:59:38 NaN NaN      NaN  12017.0
```

Comment: Almost there. What if there was not a preceding nan on column 28 index 2015-12-05 03:24:45 (or index 5 in your example) (see edit on original post). Also, the code will not work once I go further in the dataframe and there are values in columns 25 and 26.